# How to specialize ONLY one method inside a template class with many argument types

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am implementing a `HashTable` template class in C++ and its prototype is like this:

```
template<class K, class T, unsigned int containerSize=CONTAINER_SIZE>
class LPHashTableChained{
    ........

    unsigned int hashFunction(K& key);

}
```

My question is how I can specialize my `hashFunction()` method to behave differently when `K` equals string type.

I tried to implement the function with its correct format and with a second implementation where I omit the `class K` argument and put string as the type like below:

1st implementation:

```
template<class K, class T, unsigned int containerSize>
unsigned int LPHashTableChained<K,T,containerSize>::hashFunction(K& key){

}
```

2nd implementation:

```
template<class T, unsigned int containerSize>
unsigned int LPHashTableChained<string,T,containerSize>::hashFunction(const string& key){

}
```

But I get compilation errors !!!

What is the easiest way to specilize this `hashFunction` when `K= string` ???

Thanks

Comment: Functions do not allow for partial specialisation, only classes/structs do.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot partially specialize member functions of templates. (Total specializations are fine, though.)

The best approach for your class is to do as the standard library does, though, and provide the hash function as a "policy"-type template argument:

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename Hash = std::hash<K>>
class HashTable
{
  Hash hasher;
  // use hasher(x)
};
```

Now you can simply specialise the hasher for your string type, or provide your own:

```
// provide custom

struct MyInsaneHasher { std::size_t operator()(const Foo &) const; };
HashTable<Foo, int, MyInsaneHasher> m1;

// add specialization for `std::hash`:

namespace std
{
  template <> struct hash<Bar> { size_t operator()(const Bar&) const; };
}
HashTable<Bar, int> m2;
```

Comment: do you mean changing the class declaration as follows:

    template<class K, class T, typename Hash=std::hash<K>, unsigned int containerSize=CONTAINER_SIZE>
    class LPHashTableChained{
     .....
    };

and by specializing the hasher you mean what exactly ? i have never used this before.

Comment: @LambrosPetrou: yes, something like that.

Comment: what about the hasher ??? how do i overload it ?? is it in the standard library already and i just need to overload the string type ?

Comment: i am sorry but i cannot find how i can specialize the Hasher just for one type. If you could please write a small example just returning 0 in order to see how i can implement it i would grateful.

Comment: OK, done. I think you should study carefully the interface of `std::unordered_map` for a couple of hours to see an expert solution to your approach; that'll give you good ideas.

Comment: ok thanks for the help! i will...at the moment though i fixed my issue with a relatively easy solution till that study :P